# geting a custom function to "live" to a ajax result

Tags: jquery

I have a function that basically can make any non live function a live function

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        collapsiblePanel: function() {
            // Call the ConfigureCollapsiblePanel function for the selected element
            return $(this).each(ConfigureCollapsiblePanel);
        }
    });

})(jQuery);

function ConfigureCollapsiblePanel() {
    $(this).addClass("ui-widget");

    // Wrap the contents of the container within a new div.
    $(this).children().wrapAll("<div class='collapsibleContainerContent ui-widget-content'></div>");

    // Create a new div as the first item within the container.  Put the title of the panel in here.
    $("<div class='collapsibleContainerTitle ui-widget-header'><div>" + $(this).attr("title") + "</div></div>").prependTo($(this));

    // Assign a call to CollapsibleContainerTitleOnClick for the click event of the new title div.
    $(".collapsibleContainerTitle", this).click(CollapsibleContainerTitleOnClick);
}

function CollapsibleContainerTitleOnClick() {
    // The item clicked is the title div... get this parent (the overall container) and toggle the content within it.
    $(".collapsibleContainerContent", $(this).parent()).slideToggle();
}

     (function ($) {
 $.fn.livecollapsiblePanel = function (opts) {
        this.live("mouseover", function() {
            if (!$(this).data("init")) {
                $(this).data("init", true).collapsiblePanel(opts);
            }
        });
        return $();
    };
}(jQuery));
     $(".collapsibleContainer").livecollapsiblePanel();
```

what i ma basically doing is generating collapsible panels in a ajax call and showing it in div.  in order for me to 'activate' the each div into into a collapsible panel i currently need to mouse over each div which then converts to collapsible panel... is there any way i can change that to when the divs load up form the ajax call they become collapsible panels.

Comment: You know that `.live()` is deprecated, don't you?

Comment: yes.. but i am using 1.7.1 and it seems ot work...

Comment: i can chnage that to delegate ....but my main thing is instead of mouseover can i use another event that make the this function act on the dom as soon as the dom is placed on the page (once the ajax call is completed) without the user needing to intereact with the dom

Comment: Why don't you just remove the `mouseover` event alltoghether and start off from the `if()` statement?

Comment: well i have to have that live / delgate or on ....otherwise it wont work...

Comment: i tired on with the lates jquery and it doensnt work at alll...